# Создание нескольких объектов Button с отступом на форме

Tags: c#, winforms

Как можно динамически создать экземпляры дочернего класса Button так, чтобы каждый следующий экземпляр появлялся с заданным постоянным горизонтальным отступом? Иными словами, нужно свойство Button, которое определяет отступ от соседнего элемента управления (пробовал Margin - не работает). Тогда можно будет задать его в конструкторе.

В итоге должно произойти следующее:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
{
    var btn = Controls[i] as Button;
    btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, (btn.Width + 30) * i);
}
```

Но `Location` должен определяться при создании экземпляра, не располагая информацией о номере кнопки на форме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, задавать нужные координаты можно сразу при создании контролов:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var btn = new Button();

    btn.Location = new Point(30, 30 * i);
    //btn.Location = new Point(30 + i * 5, 30 * i);

    btn.Text = "Click me";
    btn.Parent = this; //this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Во-вторых, можно использовать такие контейнеры, как [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zah8ywcc(v=vs.110).aspx) и [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3a1tbfwd(v=vs.110).aspx). Они автоматически выстраивают вложенные контролы внутри себя.

Например, добавьте на форму `FlowLayoutPanel`, задайте ей нужные размеры, укажите свойство `FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown`.

После чего можно добавить кнопки на эту панель без указания их местоположения. Они автоматически выстроятся в ряд сверху вниз, как мы указали выше. При этом учитывается свойство `Margin`, так что можно им пользоваться при необходимости.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var btn = new Button();

    btn.Margin = new Padding(10);
    //btn.Margin = new Padding(left: i * 5, top: 5, right: 0, bottom: 0);

    btn.Text = "Click me";
    btn.Parent = flowLayoutPanel; //flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: Второй случай подходит больше для определения общего отступа.

Comment: Тогда в конструкторе класса `MyButton : Button` можно будет просто указать `Parent = flowLayoutPanel;`. Но будет ли разница между `Form.Controls.Add(new MyButton())` и `flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new MyButton())`, если свойство `Parent` определяется в конструкторе?

Comment: @tryphosa - Сработает то, что вызывается последним. То есть сперва сработает конструктор `MyButton`, а потом `Controls.Add`. В итоге экземпляр кнопки поместится в коллекцию этого родительского контрола.

Comment: @tryphosa - обновил ответ. В комментариях добавил пример увеличения отступа.